# radio buttons not returning 1st value

Tags: php, mysql

i have two radio buttons

```
<input type="radio" name="fangspotted" value="yes"> YES 
<input type="radio" name="testRadio" value="no"> NO
```

Here is my PHP code to get the POST value

```
$fang_spotted=$_POST['fangspotted'];

"INSERT INTO TABLE1(coulmn) VALUES ('" .$fang_spotted. "')";
```

i am getting error when i select "yes" option from radio button but getting "no" when "no" option is selected

Comment: I want to know what the aliens did.  Also you should sanitize those database inputs before Bobby Tables strikes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U have to use the same name on both radiobuttons